# how can i make a wp category sidebar with image with multi background color

Tags: php, sidebar

I want to make something like this:

[image]

I install SF [Taxonomy Thumbnail plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXSx3.jpg) in wp and use this code:

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'category';
$args = array('with_thumbnail' => true, // true = retrieve terms that has    thumbnail, false = retrieve all terms
);
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, $args);

if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '<li><a href="/index.php/' . $taxonomy . '/' . $term-           >slug . '"style="display:block;width:90px;height:90px;background: linear-gradient(to right,  #FF8E88 0%,#f4716a 100%);"><div  class="cat-back-two"><center>'  . get_term_thumbnail(   $term->term_taxonomy_id,  $size = 'category-thumb', $attr = '' ). '<div   class="txt1">' . $term->name .  '</div></center></div></a></li> ';
    }
    echo '</ul>';

}
?>
```

With CSS be like this:

[image]

I don't know PHP. How can I make it like the first image (with 3 color background)?

Comment: Have you tried asking on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com as well?

Comment: they answer :it's not actually about WordPress  (it is specifically asking about PHP/CSS), and as such might be considered off-topic here. Stack Overflow might be a more appropriate place for your question :|

Comment: is there any answers ?